# Raspberry Pi with MIDI keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I consider to acquire Raspberry Pi for MIDI keyboard.

The question is do you aware about any problem with latency.I usually use amsynth  and zynaddsubfx. I don't know whether it's possible to use pulseaudio and jack on 
Raspberry Pi, because it might be resource consuming and will cause a latency.

If you aware about any problem with latency on Raspberry Pi with MIDI processor, please let me know, I don't want to buy it and not using it.